# Can I get confidence interval instead of prediction interval using forecast.Arima (package forecast)?

Tags: r, forecasting

Hi I understand roughly the differences between confidence interval and prediction interval (see post from [Rob Hyndman](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/intervals/) and the [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/difference-between-confidence-intervals-and-prediction-intervals) on crossvalidated). And that prediction interval is much wider than confidence interval.

My question is can I get the confidence interval from `forecast.Arima`? Why is only prediction interval rather than confidence interval calculated from `forecast`?
In the document of forecast:

```
forecast(object, h=10, level=c(80,95), fan=FALSE, lambda=NULL, 
    bootstrap=FALSE, npaths=5000, biasadj=FALSE, ...)
```

`level` is confidence level for prediction intervals.

Comment: No. But why would you want them?

Comment: @RobHyndman Thanks Rob for the reply. I'm just curious. What if I'm interested to know the confidence interval associated with the mean value of Y E[Y|x]? Why here prediction interval is more interesting than confidence interval? Thx and I appreciate your blog & book!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prediction intervals are useful because in forecasting you usually want to know the uncertainty of a future observation.

I can't think why you would ever need a confidence interval for a future mean, but here is an example showing how you could compute it:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
fc <- forecast(fit, h=20, level=95)
sim <- matrix(NA, ncol=20,nrow=1000)
for(i in 1:1000)
  sim[i,] <- simulate(fit,20)
se <- apply(sim,2,sd)/sqrt(1000)
fc$upper <- fc$mean + 1.96*se
fc$lower <- fc$mean - 1.96*se
plot(fc)
```

[image]